# Date & Time causing 'unable to install xcode project' error

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm making a day streak counter-- the idea is that when you do a task for x amount of consecutive days, each consecutive day adds to a overall total number (a streak). It is meant to reset if a task isn't done for 24 or more hours.
I'm doing this exclusively with userDefaults.

I'm unaware of any way to test this in simulator so I've been testing it on my phone by editing the date manually via settings. I believe this is possibly causing de-syncing issues? (i'm guessing). My only reason for assuming this is that it get a message saying:

> 'unable to install xcode project'

This seemingly goes away when reseting my date and time to automatic. I'm unable to test on other devices.

**I'm inquiring to know weather there is a mistake in my code causing this or is this normal when messing with date & time manually?**

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //User Defaults on first Load
    if defaults.object(forKey: "lastDate") == nil {
        defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "lastDate")
        print("Default 'lastDay' Set for: " + FormatDate1(date: 
        defaults.object(forKey: "lastDate") as! Date))
            }
    
       //Info
       print("Current Day is: " + FormatDate1(date: Date()))
       print("'lastDay' was: " + FormatDate1(date: defaults.object(forKey: 
       "lastDate") as! Date))
    }





    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    //Calls Function
    OneDayApart()
    
    }






   //Button Action
   @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    
   
    //Components
    let date1 = Date()
    let date2 = defaults.object(forKey: "lastDate") as! Date
    let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: date2, to: date1)
    print("The difference In Hours Is: \(difference.hour!)")
    
    //If 24 hours+
       if difference.hour! >= 24 || difference.hour! <= -24 {
       print("The difference In Hours Is Greater Than 24 So DayNumber is Reset to 0")
       defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "lastDate")
       defaults.set(0, forKey: "DayNumber")
        
    //If same day
    } else if Calendar.current.isDate(date1, inSameDayAs:date2) == true {
        print("Current Day is: " + FormatDate1(date: Date()))
        defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "lastDate")
        print("Same day as before, But 'lastDay' is reset for: " + FormatDate1(date: 
        defaults.object(forKey: "lastDate") as! Date))
        print("Streak: " + String(defaults.integer(forKey: "DayNumber")))

    //If Different DAY && It's been LESS than 24 Hours
    } else if Calendar.current.isDate(date1, inSameDayAs:date2) == false && 
    difference.hour! < 24 {
        print("This is a different day")
        defaults.set(Date(), forKey: "lastDate")
        print("The New 'lastDay': " + FormatDate1(date: defaults.object(forKey: 
        "lastDate") as! Date))
        let addedNumber = defaults.integer(forKey: "DayNumber") + 1
        defaults.set(addedNumber, forKey: "DayNumber")
        print("Streak: " + String(defaults.integer(forKey: "DayNumber")))
    }
    
      //Let Label Equal Number
      streakNumberLabel.text = String(defaults.integer(forKey: "DayNumber"))
    }



  //FORMATS DATE
  func FormatDate1(date : Date) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
   }



  //Check if it has been 24 Hours+ and Let Label Equal Number
  func OneDayApart() {
    let date1 = Date() //today
    let date2 = defaults.object(forKey: "lastDate") as! Date //last day
    let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: date2, to: date1)
    print("The difference In Hours Is: \(difference.hour!)")
    
    //HAS IT BEEN MORE THAN 24 HOURS?
    if difference.hour! >= 24 || difference.hour! <= -24 {
    print("The difference In Hours Is Greater Than 24 So DayNumber is Reset to 0")
    defaults.set(0, forKey: "DayNumber")
    }
    
    //Let Label Equal Number
    streakNumberLabel.text = String(defaults.integer(forKey: "DayNumber"))
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a free or paid developer account?  Did you set your time forward?  If you set your time forward beyond the validity of the provisioning profile and then set it back, the provisioning profile is still marked invalid.  This is to prevent people from running expired apps by setting their clock backward.  You can either change your Mac time to affect the simulator time, or simply modify your code to add an offset to the current time for testing purposes

Comment: I have a free dev account. This was actually very helpful, I thought I read something about this not working (changing date on computer) but I must have been mistaken so thankyou